# React Native calling another .js inside App.js render

Tags: react-native

Is it possible to call another render() inside my App.js render. I just start working with react native, so it might look stupid.

I create the following file. Splash.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native'
export default class Splash extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.title}></Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 18
  }
})
```

How can I call it inside my App.js to be the default page?

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';


export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      // Call the Splash.js
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to call render() inside a render() function. You can convert your splash component into a functional component, which just returns the JSX:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View, Text} from 'react-native';

export default function Splash() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Splash</Text>
      </View>
    );
}
```

Your app component will then render the returned JSX like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import Splash from './your-path-to-the-splash-file'

export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Splash/>
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

You should check out the official react docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html